# popup a headerview/layout whenever keyboard showed in edittext

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Am stuck with a pretty simple issue in myapp .  i have a custom dialog which has **EditText** and whenever softkeyboard opensup i want to show header/a another layout on dialog layout(see picture with three textviews ). if he clicks on done. hidethesoftkeyboard along with header.

```
        ettagmsg = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etFlyTagName);
```

popup header

```
        LinearLayout layheader = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.header_buttons);
```

[image]

Comment: not sure I understand your question, are you trying to detect when the keyboard show n hide so u can show n hide a view ?

Comment: I wanted show  the layout which is having three textviews whenever keyboardshowedup..

Answer (score 1):

you might want to add this listener!

```
 ettagmsg.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){

      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if(v.hasFocus()){
            layheader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }else{
            layheader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //hide soft input here
          }
      }
}
```

Hope i was of use!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't really tested this out but here's a nice snippet that should work: http://felhr85.net/2014/05/04/catch-soft-keyboard-showhidden-events-in-android/

tl;dr: since popping up the soft keyboard requires that some views get flattened (height becomes smaller), you can use that to check if the soft keyboard is hidden/shown.

Answer (score 0):

keyboards are pretty annoying on Android. you feel free to use this class I done before:

you instantiate it with a Listener (your dialog), and attach and detach it from view during onStart/onStop or similar callbacks. Remember you want to attach it to the Dialog view.

also, you might need to adjust the `DP_KEYBOARD_THRESHOLD` value

```
public class KeyboardObserver implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

   private static final int DP_KEYBOARD_THRESHOLD = 60;
   private int keyboardThreshold;

   private int currentHeight;
   private View view;
   private final KeyboardListener listener;
   private boolean isKeyboardShown = false;

   public KeyboardObserver(KeyboardListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
   }

   public void attachToView(View view) {

      keyboardThreshold = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
         TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DP_KEYBOARD_THRESHOLD, view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

      this.view = view;
      currentHeight = view.getHeight();
      view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

      if (currentHeight <= 0) {
         view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(this);
      }

   }

   public void detachFromView() {
      if (view != null) view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
      int newHeight = view.getHeight();
      if (currentHeight > 0) {
         int diff = newHeight - currentHeight;
         if (diff < -keyboardThreshold) {
            Log.d(this, "onGlobalLayout. keyboard is show. height diff = " + -diff);
            // keyboard is show
            isKeyboardShown = true;
            if (listener != null)
               listener.onKeyboardShow(-diff);
         } else if (diff > keyboardThreshold) {
            Log.d(this, "onGlobalLayout.keyboard is hide.  height diff = " + diff);
            // keyboard is hide
            isKeyboardShown = false;
            if (listener != null)
               listener.onKeyboardHide(diff);
         } else {
            Log.v(this, "onGlobalLayout. height diff = " + diff);
         }
      }
      currentHeight = newHeight;
   }

   public boolean isKeyboardShown() {
      return isKeyboardShown;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onPreDraw() {
      currentHeight = view.getHeight();
      view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
      return true;
   }

   public interface KeyboardListener {
      public void onKeyboardShow(int height);

      public void onKeyboardHide(int height);
   }
}
```